# How to add background image in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop

I want to add a background like [blockbunny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXo7i.png) and I have a background image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkD9L.png) in my assets/images folder under the android folder. I have tried to separate the image into three sections and add it as sky, clouds and mountains in Background class. For some reason, it is throwing null pointer exception because spritebatch is null in MyMainGame class. I have initialised SpriteBatch in create method of MyMainGame class.

Here is my MyMainGame.class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.manager.Content;
import com.mygdx.manager.GameInputProcessor;

import com.mygdx.manager.GameStateManager;
import com.mygdx.manager.MyInput;


import javafx.scene.layout.Background;

import static com.mygdx.manager.Box2DVariables.PPM;

public class MyMainGame implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    public static final int Width=320;
    public static final int Height=240;
    public static final int SCALE=2;

    public static final float STEP= 1/60f;  //60 frames per second

    private float accumulator;
    private SpriteBatch sb;
    protected OrthographicCamera cam;
    protected OrthographicCamera hud;
    private Texture tex;
    private Background[] backgrounds;

    private GameStateManager gsm;

    public SpriteBatch getSb() {
        return sb;
    }

    public OrthographicCamera getCam() {
        return cam;
    }

    public OrthographicCamera getHud() {
        return hud;
    }
     public  static Content con;



    @Override
    public void create () {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GameInputProcessor());
        con=new Content();
        con.loadTexture("images//sprite.jpg","sprite");
        con.loadTexture("images//background.png","background");

        gsm=new GameStateManager(this);

        sb=new SpriteBatch();
        cam=new OrthographicCamera(160,120);


        cam.setToOrtho(false,Width/2,Height/2);
        hud=new OrthographicCamera();
        hud.setToOrtho(false,Width/2,Height/2);










    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        cam.update();
        hud.update();

        accumulator +=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        while(accumulator>=STEP){
            accumulator-=STEP;
            gsm.update(STEP);
            gsm.render();
            MyInput.update();
        }



    }
    public void resize(int width,int height){
        sb.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width, height);
     }

    public void dispose(){
            con.disposeTexture("sprite");
            con.disposeTexture("background");
    }
    public void pause(){

    }

    public void resume(){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.PLAY);
    }
}
```

GameState is an abstract class containing unimplemented methods

```
package com.mygdx.gamestate;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.game.MyMainGame;
import com.mygdx.manager.GameStateManager;

public abstract class GameState {

    protected GameStateManager gsm;
    protected MyMainGame game;
    protected SpriteBatch sb;
    protected OrthographicCamera cam;
    protected OrthographicCamera hud;

    protected GameState(GameStateManager gsm){
        this.gsm=gsm;
        game=gsm.game();
        sb=game.getSb();
        cam=game.getCam();
        hud=game.getHud();
        init();

    }

    public abstract void init();
    public abstract void update(float dt);
    public abstract void draw();
    public abstract void render();
    public abstract void handleInput();
    public abstract void dispose();



}
```

The Play class is extending GameState class

```
public class Play extends GameState{

  //  private BitmapFont font=new BitmapFont();
    private World  world;
    private Body playerBody;
    private int viewportWidth= 10 * 32 ;
    int viewportHeight= 8 * 32 ;


    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2d;
    private OrthographicCamera B2DCAM;
    private TiledMap tileMap;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer orthomap;
    private MyContactListener cl;
    private float tileSize;
    private Background[] backgrounds;
    private Texture back;



    //file name
    private final String LEVEL_1 ="maps/tilemap1.tmx";

    public Play(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);


        //setup box2d
        world=new World(new Vector2(0,-9.8f),true);
        cl=new MyContactListener();
        world.setContactListener(cl);
         sb=new SpriteBatch(1000);
        //cam=new OrthographicCamera();

        b2d=new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        //create Player
        createPlayer();
        //create Tiles
        createTiles();
        orthomap = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap,1/32f);



        //setup Box2D Cam
        B2DCAM=new OrthographicCamera();
        B2DCAM.setToOrtho(false, MyMainGame.Width/PPM,MyMainGame.Height/PPM);
        cam=new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false,10,7);


         back = MyMainGame.con.getTexture("background");



      TextureRegion sky = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 0, 320, 240);
       TextureRegion clouds = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 240, 320, 240);
       TextureRegion mountains = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 480, 320, 240);
        backgrounds = new Background[3];
       backgrounds[0] = new Background(sky,cam, 0f);
       backgrounds[1] = new Background(clouds, cam, 0.1f);
       backgrounds[2] = new Background(mountains, cam, 0.2f);







      /* //TODO - remove me
        File file = new File(LEVEL_1);
        if(file.exists())
            System.out.println("file exists");*/


    }


    @Override
    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
            world.step(dt,6,2);
            MyMainGame.con.getTexture("sprite");

        for (Background b : backgrounds) {
          b.update(dt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        //clear screen

        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      //
        cam.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4,MyMainGame.Height / 2,0);
        // cam.setToOrtho(false,playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4,MyMainGame.Height / 2);
        //cam.setPosition(playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4, MyMainGame.Height / 2);

        cam.setToOrtho(false,10,7);

       cam.update();





        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        for(int i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) {
            backgrounds[i].render(sb);
       }


        orthomap.setView(cam);
        orthomap.render();
        b2d.render(world,B2DCAM.combined);




    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput() {
     if(MyInput.isPressed((MyInput.SPACE))){
         System.out.println("space pressed");
         if(cl.isPlayerOnGround())
             System.out.println(cl.isPlayerOnGround());
             playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0,200,true);
         }
     }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        world.dispose();
        b2d.dispose();
        tileMap.dispose();
        orthomap.dispose();
    }

    private void createPlayer(){
        BodyDef bodydef=new BodyDef();
        FixtureDef fixdef=new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape=new PolygonShape();


        //create player
        bodydef.position.set(160/PPM,200/PPM);
        bodydef.type= BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        playerBody=world.createBody(bodydef);

        shape.setAsBox(5/PPM,5/PPM);
        fixdef.shape=shape;
        fixdef.filter.categoryBits= BIT_PLAYER;
        fixdef.filter.maskBits=Box2DVariables.BIT_BLUE;
        playerBody.createFixture(fixdef).setUserData("PLAYER");


        //create foot sensor
        shape.setAsBox(2/PPM,2/PPM,new Vector2(0,-5/PPM),0);
        fixdef.shape=shape;
        fixdef.filter.categoryBits= BIT_PLAYER;
        fixdef.filter.maskBits=Box2DVariables.BIT_BLUE;
        fixdef.isSensor=true;
        playerBody.createFixture(fixdef).setUserData("FOOT");
    }
    private void createTiles(){
//load tile map
        tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load(LEVEL_1);
        //orthomap = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap,1);


        tileSize=(int)tileMap.getProperties().get("tilewidth", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("Tile Size " +tileSize);

        TiledMapTileLayer layer;

        layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)tileMap.getLayers().get("Blue");
            createLayer(layer,Box2DVariables.BIT_BLUE);
        layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)tileMap.getLayers().get("Green");
        createLayer(layer,Box2DVariables.BIT_GREEN);
        layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)tileMap.getLayers().get("Red");
        createLayer(layer,Box2DVariables.BIT_RED);
        System.out.println("Layer Height " +layer.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Layer Width " +layer.getWidth());
    }
    private void createLayer(TiledMapTileLayer layer,short bits){
        BodyDef bodydef=new BodyDef();
        FixtureDef fixdef=new FixtureDef();

//go through cells in layer
        for(int row=0;row<layer.getHeight();row++){
            for(int col=0;col<layer.getWidth();col++){
                //get cells
                TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell=layer.getCell(col,row);

                //check if cell exists
                if(cell==null) continue;
                if(cell.getTile()==null) continue;

                //create body and fixture from cell
                bodydef.type= BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
                bodydef.position.set((col+0.5f)*tileSize/PPM,(row+0.5f)*tileSize/PPM);
                ChainShape cs=new ChainShape();
                Vector2[] v=new Vector2[3];
                //bottom left
                v[0]=new Vector2(-tileSize/2/PPM,-tileSize/2/PPM);
                //top left
                v[1]=new Vector2(-tileSize/2/PPM,tileSize/2/PPM);
                //top right corner
                v[2]=new Vector2(tileSize/2/PPM,tileSize/2/PPM);


                cs.createChain(v);
                fixdef.friction=0;
                fixdef.shape =cs;
                fixdef.filter.categoryBits=Box2DVariables.BIT_BLUE;
                fixdef.filter.maskBits=BIT_PLAYER;
                fixdef.isSensor=false;
                world.createBody(bodydef).createFixture(fixdef);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have loaded the Texture in MyMainClass.java and it is stored in HashMap in Content class
I am getting the background image as Texture named 'back', and seperating them as TextureRegions sky,clouds and mountains in Play constructor of Play class and passing them in Background class.

```
TextureRegion sky = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 0, 320, 240);
       TextureRegion clouds = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 240, 320, 240);
       TextureRegion mountains = new TextureRegion(back, 0, 480, 320, 240);
        backgrounds = new Background[3];
       backgrounds[0] = new Background(sky,cam, 0f);
       backgrounds[1] = new Background(clouds, cam, 0.1f);
       backgrounds[2] = new Background(mountains, cam, 0.2f);
```

Background class

```
package com.mygdx.manager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.mygdx.game.MyMainGame;

public class Background {


    private TextureRegion image;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private float scale;

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private int drawX;
    private int drawY;

    private float dx;
    private float dy;

    public Background(TextureRegion image, OrthographicCamera camera, float scale) {
        this.image = image;
        this.camera = camera;
        this.scale = scale;
        drawX = MyMainGame.Width / image.getRegionWidth() + 1;
        drawY = MyMainGame.Height / image.getRegionHeight() + 1;

        System.out.println("Image width"+image.getRegionWidth());
        System.out.println("Image height"+image.getRegionHeight());
    }

    public void setVector(float dx, float dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public void update(float ts) {
        x += (dx * scale) * ts;
        y += (dy * scale) * ts;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        float x = ((this.x + camera.viewportWidth / 2 - camera.position.x) * scale) % image.getRegionWidth();
        float y = ((this.y + camera.viewportHeight / 2 - camera.position.y) * scale) % image.getRegionHeight();

        sb.begin();

        int colXOffset = x > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        int rowYOffset = y > 0 ? -1 : 0;

        for (int rowY = 0; rowY < drawY; rowY++) {
            for (int colX = 0; colX < drawX; colX++) {
                sb.draw(image, x + (colX + colXOffset) * image.getRegionWidth(), y + (rowY + rowYOffset) * image.getRegionHeight());
            }
        }

        sb.end();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in Play class in render method as null pointer exception.Dont really know whats going on! sb.setProjectionMatrix is giving nullpointer exception!

```
 public void render() {

        //clear screen

        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      //
        cam.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4,MyMainGame.Height / 2,0);
        // cam.setToOrtho(false,playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4,MyMainGame.Height / 2);
        //cam.setPosition(playerBody.getPosition().x * PPM +MyMainGame.Width / 4, MyMainGame.Height / 2);

        cam.setToOrtho(false,10,7);

       cam.update();





        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        for(int i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) {
            backgrounds[i].render(sb);
       }


        orthomap.setView(cam);
        orthomap.render();
        b2d.render(world,B2DCAM.combined);




    }
```

How do I split the background image and add it as shown above in my Game?

Comment: You have two different SpriteBatch variables in your game class, and you left one of them is null. You also instantiate another SpriteBatch in at least one of your game state classes. (sorry, too much code to read carefully). All these redundant variables and objects needlessly instantiated multiple times will lead to all kinds of bugs.

Comment: Your Play class extends GameState. GameState.sb refers to the same SpriteBatch from the Game, but Play overwrites it with a new one.

Comment: Ontop of that it seems the three TextureRegion objects (sky, clouds, mountains) are created from the same Texture. Drawing them one ontop of each other is redundant. You need three separate image files each being one layer of the whole background image so that the background will draw the way you want.